# Dispatching event from eventListener in react and close popup window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, dispatch

I am still new to react and I am trying to call `dispatch()` on response in react but the page never stops loading as shown in the snapshot below.

Here is my code...

*profile/index.jsx*

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {profileOperations} from "state/profile";

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const openPopup = () => {
    const popupWindow = window.open('', POPUP_WINDOW, windowParams);
    attachEvent(popupWindow);
};

const attachEvent = popupWindow => {
    window.addEventListener(
         'message',
         function(event){
               if (event.data &&
                   typeof event.data !== 'undefined') {             
                   dispatch(profileOperations.saveProfile(event));
                   popupWindow.close();
               }
         },
         false
    );
);

const windowParams = () => {
   const threeDSPopupHeight = 500;
   const threeDSPopupWidth = isMobileDevice ? 360 : 600;
   const popupLeftPosition = leftPosition(threeDSPopupWidth);
   const popupTopPosition = topPosition(threeDSPopupHeight);
   return `resizable=yes, toolbar=no, screenX=${popupLeftPosition}, screenY=${popupTopPosition}, menubar=no, scrollbar=yes, width= ${threeDSPopupWidth}, height=${threeDSPopupHeight}, top= ${popupTopPosition}, left=${popupLeftPosition}`;
};
```

*profile/operations.js*

```
export const saveProfile = event => dispatch => {
    try {
        const response  = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (response.profiles) {
            dispatch(processProfile(response));
        } else if(response.statusCode){
            console.log('body contains error');
            dispatch(resourceErrorHandler(response))
        }
    } catch {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Here are sample responses on server side. I test by passing `profile` or `error` variables in below code to client side:

*handleCallback.js*

```
module.exports = ({ error, response = {}, body }, res) => {
    const profile = '{"profiles":[{"id":"515592671","token":"8416003642718270"}]}';
    const error = '{"message": "Internal Error with Browser", "statusCode": 500, "code": 1004}';
    res.send("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
        +  "const data = "+JSON.stringify(profile)+";"
        + " window.opener.postMessage(data, \"http://localhost\");"
        + "</script>");
};
```

*Success:*

```
{
    "profiles": [{
        "id": "515592671",
        "token": "8416003642718270"
    }]
}
```

*Error:*

```
{
    "message": "Internal Error with Browser",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "code": 1004
}
```

[image]

So, I have few problems with this code:

1. Popup sometimes opens in new tab instead of a popup window
2. The console is flooded with above messages in the snapshot
3. The popup should close after everything was done loading in saveProfile
4. How do I limit event listener to only listen to above success/error responses

Comment: Why do you listen to window events with name "message"? This seems to be a very specific but at the same time common event name (perhaps used natively by the browser?) Did you try to use something more specific?

Comment: I have not. Because it looks like the event.type is a message. what kind do you think I should use?

Comment: I don't know... In your index.jsx there is such a binding but givent the code you exposed it's hard to tell why it's needed